# Authenticating a User against a client in Keycloak

Tags: javascript, keycloak, openid-connect

I have a Keycloak server setup with a realm and a client.  I have Authorization setup on the client and I'm able to evaluate the authentication within the admin interface.

When I click "Show authorization data", I can see in the response an `authorization` attribute with `permissions`.

I have a web client that uses a redirect via keycloak for oidc authentication. I would like to limit which keyclock users are able to login into the client, so I would like to authorise the login, but I'm unable to see the `authorization` attribute in the JWT.

Am I completely misunderstanding how this works, or is there something I can do to see that attribute?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've finally go my head around it. Short answer - I needed to RTFM.

Long answer - I needed to hit the token endpoint twice.  The first time with grant_type = `authorization_code` to get the access token.  Then again with grant_type = `urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:uma-ticket` (and with the access token in the header) to get the keycloak client to authenticate.

If the second response comes back as 403 - access_denied, then I reject the login,  otherwise, I allow the user to login into my system.

The specific bit I needed can be found in the docs is here: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/6.0/authorization_services/#_service_obtaining_permissions